# Laravel Queue Work Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

**The Scenario**

Im following a tutorial on youtube of how to setup a queue worker whilst reading the latest laravel documentations on it. Ive followed each step correctly up to the point where i now have to run the worker.

Running the worker however executes the job 255 times. Im not sure if its failing "But i imagine it is since the email isnt being sent", but nothing is happening.

My question is similar to this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-event-queue-255-attemps-and-freeze-no-listener-actions-done

But that user has failed to properly answer their own question.

**My Files**

*Auth Controller:*

```
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'full_name' => 'required',
            'email'     => 'required|unique:users',
            'password'  => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        //Authenticate the user
        Auth::login($user);

        //Queue the email
        EmailNewUsers::dispatch();

        return 'Email Sent!';

        //Redirect User
//        return redirect('admin/dashboard');
    }
```

*EmailNewUsers Job:*

```
class EmailNewUsers implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        MailController::UserRegistered();
    }
}
```

*MailController*

```
class MailController extends Controller
{
    public static function UserRegistered()
    {
        Mail::to(Auth::user())->send(new UserRegistered());
    }
}
```

*UserRegistered Mailable*

```
class UserRegistered extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.UserRegistered');
    }
}
```

**The Question**

Why is the queue worker running a job 255 times then doing nothing afterwards..?

**Edit**

So i got it working by changing nothing.. just went out for lunch came back in refreshed and boom it worked... for about 10 tries, then back to the same old error.

This time i tried making a new Job to dispatch called "TestJob" I setup test job following the tutorial and it worked intially, then 30 seconds later it stopped working when i retried the same job.

[image]

Note the time of the first processing -> processed and then the error again. Im not sure if this will help anything but i thought id add it.

Answer (score 0):

MailController has error, [append](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs) `failed_job` table and view error log

Comment: I've done this, its not displaying anything after ive re-ran everything. Also unless i run `php artisan migrate:fresh` the queue does not take any further actions

Comment: are you sure that class UserRegistered exists?

Comment: Yes im sure it exists, its a mailable

Comment: Maybe u need configure `.env` file `MAIL_*` section

Comment: The mail is configured, i sent dummy emails to mailtrap before configuring the que, everything works fine without the queue its just when i try using it, nothing works.

Comment: [Cleaning Up After Failed Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs)
Append method:
`public function failed(Exception $exception){\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::info($exception);}`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the queue to attempt 255 times, you need to define how many times it has to try.

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=3
```

If Job fails after 3 tries a row will be inserted in 'failed_jobs' table. Look in 'exception' column for errors.

If you don't have 'failed_jobs' run this command

```
php artisan queue:failed-table
```

Then run

```
php artisan migrate
```